# Words for a place that a group of birds might be

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for single words that could replace "coop" in the following sentence.  It must be specifically related to birds.

> The birds are in the coop.

I have come up with several options, but I'm looking for more.

Already considered: aviary, hatchery, henhouse, roost, menagerie.

There's not a particular structure I have in mind. I'm looking for the word that feels most fitting for my bird themed project. It might be more accurate to say I'm looking for the name of a place a group of birds (free or captive) would "call home."

Comment: What kind of place do you have in mind?  Birds can be in the aviary, in the sky, in the trees ...

Comment: @Jim This is somewhere the would land, so not in the sky.

Comment: *dovecote, mews, nest, aerie, birdhouse*.

Comment: Are you looking for names for anywhere they might land or do you have a particular structure in mind for which you don’t know the name?  If the latter, can you describe the structure for us?

Comment: There's not a particular structure I had in mind. Just looking for the word that feels most fitting for my bird themed project. It might be more accurate to say I'm looking for somewhere a group of birds would "call home."

Comment: Are these free birds or captive birds?

Comment: @Jim Either one works.

Comment: What kind of birds?

Comment: [Colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_colony) seems to refer to a particular location.

Comment: Already in your list, but *roost* seems to fit.

Comment: In my understanding a ***colony*** is the collection of birds rather than a location.  The colony may always nest in a particular location.  But note my usage here.

Comment: Why are you rejecting the words you have listed?

Comment: They aren't explicitly rejected, but I want more ideas before making a decision.

Comment: I do like *roost*.  I think that's the place birds feel most comfortable, if I think beyond the individual bird.  I will not write an answer because there was a good *roost* answer and I'd like to see it restored. // Birds congregate around the bird feeder and on a telephone line, if that helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially asking for a very extensive list of synonyms / close classmates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***colony*** is a group of birds of one or more species that nest or roost at a particular location.

Paraphrased from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_colony).

The word ***colony*** does generally refer to a place, rather than to its inhabitants.

Comment: There is nothing in the Wiki article that suggests *colony* refers to the place.  If that were true one would say things like, “This used to be a colony for auks” but instead what is actually said is, “a colony of auks used to nest here.”

Comment: @Jim there is, in the very first sentence: "A bird colony is a large congregation of individuals of one or more species of bird that nest or roost in proximity *at a particular location*".

Comment: You and I apparently interpret that sentence ***very*** differently.   “A colony is a congregation of individuals...”

Answer (score 1):

on a farm:   hen house.

in the wild:   wildlife refuge -- albeit a bit of a stretch.

nesting grounds: [rookeries](https://www.thespruce.com/glossary-definition-rookery-385367)

In general (and yes IAANAM -- National Audubon Member), there's no generic name for a location where many birds of one species congregate.   They really don't have homes per se.

Comment: OP already mentioned 'hen house'.

Comment: +1 for rookeries.  I added a link for rookeries, and you may want to expand your answer by adding a brief definition for rookery.

Comment: Only marginally less broad than *rookery* (applicable to all sociable corvids, not just rooks) is *heronry* (applicable to all social-nesting herons)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's okay to provide a word, plus documentation, even when the word was suggested in the question.

Comment: @aparente001 'I'm looking for single words that could replace "coop" in the following sentence. ' ... 'Already considered: ... henhouse, roost,  ...' is neither a request for detailed treatments nor a request for 'You're right with X' endorsements. But thanks for the redirection; a request for a list usually needs a close-vote.

Answer (score -1):

In [Aristophanes' play *The Birds*](http://johnstoniatexts.x10host.com/aristophanes/birdshtml.html)<sup>1</sup>, the birds were planning a bird homeland-in-the-sky to be called [Νεφελοκοκκυγία](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%CE%9D%CE%B5%CF%86%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BA%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1&oldid=45820114)<sup>2</sup>, which is most often translated as ***Cloud-Cuckoo Land*** in English. From the play:

> PISTHETAIROS
>   Then the first point I’d advise you of is this:                                        <sub><sup>[550]</sup></sub>
>   there should be one single city of the birds.
>   . . .
>   PISTHETAIROS
>   First, we have to name our city, something
>   fine and grand.
>   . . .
>   PISTHETAIROS
>   Well, then,
>   how do you like this: **Cloudcuckooland**?
>
> CHORUS LEADER
>   Yes! That’s good! You’ve come up with a name                 <sub><sup>1090</sup></sub>       <sub><sup>[820]</sup></sub>
>   that’s really wonderful—it’s great!

Thus it is literally

> the name of a place a group of birds (free or captive) would [like to] "call home."

Unfortunately, it's now become something of a [synonym for an unrealistic utopian belief](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cloud-cuckoo-land),<sup>3</sup> but I could see using it for the home of a lot of birds of various species, especially if the home is a constructed sanctuary or otherwise especially welcoming to birds.

Alternatively, you could use [***the bush***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bush) for a safe place *in the wild* for birds, as in the saying [*A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-bird-in-the-hand-is-worth-two-in-the-bush)<sup>4</sup>. It would also be consistent with the specialized meaning of the phrase as a tract of wilderness. From Cambridge Dictionaries:

> [ <sub><sup>U</sup></sub> ] (esp. in Australia and Africa) an area of land covered with bushes and trees that has never been farmed and where few people live

I think you would be understood on a couple of levels if you said something like

> The birds are in **the bush**, safe from human hands.

---

<sup>1</sup> The quoted text is Ian Johnston's translation of *The Birds*, via Vancouver Island University
<sup>2</sup> See Wiktionary
<sup>3</sup> See Cambridge Dictionary
<sup>4</sup> Ibid.